# How do the Cylon base stars move when not using FTL?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, propulsion

In Battlestar Galactica - The Plan movie, we see Cylon basestars appear around Caprica using FTL and they start positioning themselves for the nuclear attack:

[image]

How do the Cylon basestars propel themselves when not moving at FTL speeds. I was not able to spot any nozzle or electric propulsion system unlike Galactica. So how do they move?

Comment: wasn't there once during the Cylon Civil War when a rebel basestar took a nuke for Galactica by moving in front of it? I can't seem to find the episode.

Comment: http://media.battlestarwiki.org/images/thumb/3/37/Synthgravity1.jpg/640px-Synthgravity1.jpg - Note that gravity control is a technology seen in TRS. It's likely that Base Stars use this tech

Comment: Why would you always need Newton's third law?

Answer (score 1):

There is no on screen or behind the scenes answer to this question. Much of the base star tech is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

ITs probably a reactionless form of propulsion using gravity fields to push and pull the basestar around. It would negate the need for fuel in engines like the Battlestars use.

Comment: They would still need fuel for energy, just not for reaction mass.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia entry for cylon base stars has the following snippet about cylon base stars:

[image]

This snippet does; however, only refer to the 1978 version of the show. The 2004 battlestar galactica page mentions nothing as to the propulsion on the basestars. **The only assumptions we can make is that the propulsion systems are the same on both of the ships, regardless of the fact that no in canon information presents itself.**